# Is there a "nuclear option" regarding the election of a constitutional judge in Germany?

Tags: voting, supreme-court, germany

In Germany, the parliament has just [agreed on a successor](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/inland/neuer-bundesverfassungsrichter-gruene-unterstuetzen-stephan-harbarth-15883843.html) for one of the judges of the constitutional court. The candidate has to be elected in parliament with 2/3 of the votes as well as the majority of all members.

As smaller parties can therefore have a blocking minority, this lead to informal agreements of the parliament fractions who alternatingly support the candidate of the others (it's a bit more complicated as this, see [BPB - "Handwörterbuch des politischen Systems der Bundesrepublik Deutschland" / Bundesverfassungsgericht, Section 4, Par. 4](http://www.bpb.de/nachschlagen/lexika/handwoerterbuch-politisches-system/202000/bundesverfassungsgericht?p=all), and also [sometimes disregarded (Legal Tribune Online, 12.02.2008)](https://www.lto.de/recht/justiz/j/wahl-verfassungsrichter-gruene-vorschlagsrecht-eichberger-nachfolge/).

However, as far as I could find in the laws (see below), this required 2/3 of the votes is not mandated by the constitution, but in the "Law about the federal constitutional court" (BVerfGG). Laws can be changed with simple majority in parliament.

- **Could a simple majority in parliament and state chamber (Bundesrat) therefore replace this requirement and elect a candidate by altering the BVerfGG as a "nuclear option" [similar to the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_option#2017:_Supreme_Court_nominations)?**
- If the parliament cannot agree within 2 months, the court itself proposes three candidates (BVerfGG §7a (1)). **What happens if the parliament cannot agree with 2/3 of the votes on one of them?**

Laws I could find:

[Art. 94(1) GG (Constitution)](https://dejure.org/gesetze/GG/94.html)

> (1) Das Bundesverfassungsgericht besteht aus Bundesrichtern und anderen Mitgliedern. Die Mitglieder des Bundesverfassungsgerichtes werden je zur Hälfte vom Bundestage und vom Bundesrate gewählt. Sie dürfen weder dem Bundestage, dem Bundesrate, der Bundesregierung noch entsprechenden Organen eines Landes angehören.
>
> The federal constitutional court consists of federal judges and other
> members. Half of the members of the constitutional court are elected by
> parliament, half by the state chamber. They must not be members of parliament,
> the state chamber, the federal government or any analogous organ on the state
> level.

[BVerfGG §6 (1) (normal law)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bverfgg/__6.html)

> (1) Die vom Bundestag zu berufenden Richter werden auf Vorschlag des Wahlausschusses nach Absatz 2 ohne Aussprache mit verdeckten Stimmzetteln gewählt. Zum Richter ist gewählt, wer eine Mehrheit von zwei Dritteln der abgegebenen Stimmen, mindestens die Mehrheit der Stimmen der Mitglieder des Bundestages auf sich vereinigt.
>
> The judges to be elected by parliament are elected after proposal of the
> parliamentary election commmittee following paragraph (2) without formal
> debate and in secret ballot. Who has a majority of two thirds of the votes and the majority of the
> votes of all members of parliament, is elected.

[BVerfGG §7a (1)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bverfgg/__7a.html)

> Kommt innerhalb von zwei Monaten nach dem Ablauf der Amtszeit oder dem vorzeitigen Ausscheiden eines Richters die Wahl eines Nachfolgers auf Grund der Vorschriften des § 6 nicht zustande, so hat das älteste Mitglied des Wahlausschusses unverzüglich das Bundesverfassungsgericht aufzufordern, Vorschläge für die Wahl zu machen.
>
> When there is no agreement on a successor within two months after the judge
> quit because of §6, the oldest member of the election committee has to immediately request
> proposals from the constitutional court

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, there is.**

Recently, there are two newspaper articles published that deal with this (referencing each other).
In one of them, the minister of justice of the state of Hamburg has called to write the two-thirds majority into the Constitution for that matter.

(*Translations* are mine)

["Ein Volkskanzler" [A chancellor of the people], Maximilian Steinbeis, *Verfassungsblog*](https://verfassungsblog.de/ein-volkskanzler/):

This is a scenario, where a party gains the absolute majority. It is possible for that party to make important changes to the workings of the constitutional court:

> Die neue Regierung profitiert davon, dass die Regel, dass die
>   Richterinnen und Richter am Bundesverfassungsgericht mit
>   Zweidrittelmehrheit gewählt werden müssen, bereits seit einigen Jahren
>   abgeschafft ist. Das hatte die vorherige Mehrheit getan. Im letzten
>   Bundestag besaß die jetzige Regierungspartei schon eine
>   Sperrminorität. Die „Altparteien“, wie sie jetzt allgemein genannt
>   werden, wollten damals um jeden Preis verhindern, dass die neue Partei
>   bei der Besetzung frei werdender Posten am Bundesverfassungsgericht
>   ein Mitspracherecht für sich erzwingt.
>
> Theoretisch könnte die neue Bundestagsmehrheit jetzt diese
>   Zweidrittelmehrheit natürlich auch selber abschaffen. Dafür bräuchte
>   sie nicht einmal die Zustimmung des Bundesrates.
>
> *The new government benefits from the fact that the judges at the
>   Bundesverfassungsgericht need no two-thirds majority anymore. The majority
>   in the previous Bundestag had already abolished that rule. Because the 
>   now-governing party already had a blocking minority in the previous Bundestag, the 
>   "legacy parties", as the parties that were in power previously are now commonly 
>   called, wanted to prevent the new party to enforce influence on the selection of 
>   constitutional judges via this blocking minority.*
>
> ***Of course, the new party could have abolished the two-thirds majority vote 
>   with their present simple majority all the same. They wouldn't even need the 
>   Bundesrat [chamber of the states] to consent.***

[Wie schützt man das Grundgesetz vor seinen Feinden? [How to protect the constitution from its enemies?], *Frankfurter Allgemeine Zeitung*, "Aktualisiert am 07.11.2019"](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/inland/wie-schuetzt-man-das-grundgesetz-vor-seinen-feinden-16470117.html)

> Der neue Kanzler setzt beim Bundesverfassungsgericht an und schafft dort einen 
>   dritten Senat, der für das Staatsorganisationsrecht zuständig ist.
>
> Die Hälfte der Richter in diesem Senat werden von der Partei des
>   Kanzlers bestimmt, die in diesem Szenario die Mehrheit im Bundestag
>   hat. Eine Zweidrittelmehrheit ist für die Wahl nicht mehr
>   erforderlich, die hat der Bundestag schon abgeschafft.
>
> Gesetze, die die Regierungsmehrheit beschlossen hat, halten künftig
>   vor dem Bundesverfassungsgericht, weil sie nur die Hälfte der Richter
>   – nämlich diejenigen, die der Bundesrat wählt – für verfassungswidrig
>   hält.
>
> *The new Chancellor will start at the Federal Constitutional Court,
>   where he will create a third senate responsible for state organisation
>   law. [For which Bundestag and Bundesrat will each elect a new first group 
>   of judges, each of them half, like it is written in the constitution]*
>
> *Half of the judges in this Senate are appointed by the Chancellor's
>   Party, which has the majority in the Bundestag in this scenario. A
>   two-thirds majority is no longer required for the election, which the
>   Bundestag has already abolished.*
>
> ***In the future, laws passed by the government majority will not be
>   considered unconstitutional by the Federal Constitutional Court anymore
>   because only half of the judges will consider it unconstitutional -- 
>   namely those elected by the Bundesrat [i.e. are not elected by the 
>   chancellor's party]***
>
> ...
>
> Die Regeln über das Bundesverfassungsgericht finden sich zum größten
>   Teil nicht im Grundgesetz. ...
>
> Alles andere – die Zweidrittelmehrheit für die Wahl eines Richters,
>   die Anzahl der Senate, die Anzahl der Richter in einem Senat, die
>   Amtszeit, die Altersgrenze, der Ausschluss der Wiederwahl – stehen im
>   Bundesverfassungsgerichtsgesetz geschrieben, einem einfachen Gesetz,
>   das mit einfacher Mehrheit im Bundestag geändert werden kann.
>   [Hamburgs] Justizsenator Steffen findet es daher erwägenswert, etwa die
>   qualifizierte Mehrheit für die Richterwahl im Grundgesetz zu
>   verankern.
>
> *Most of the rules governing the Federal Constitutional Court are not found in the 
>   Basic Law.* ...
>
> ... ***[T]he two-thirds majority for the election
>   of a judge, the number of senates, the number of judges in a senate,
>   the term of office, the age limit, the exclusion of re-election - is
>   written in the Federal Constitutional Court Act, a simple law that can
>   be changed with a simple majority in the Bundestag***. Justice Senator
>   Steffen [of Hamburg] therefore finds it worth considering, for example, anchoring
>   the qualified majority for the election of judges in the Constitution.

Answer (score 3):

The law is extremely vague, but it the process is intended to start 3 months before the end of term of an existing judges duration of office. If they can't manage after 2 months then the existing court must propose 3 (per open position) candidates. The electing body (parliament or Rat) must then vote again, they are still allowed to choose a candidate of their own. It implies that they must either pick one of the 3 or an own candidate but must choose someone.

Perhaps interesting is article 4:

> § 4
>
> 1. Die Amtszeit der Richter dauert zwölf Jahre, längstens bis zur Altersgrenze.
> 2. Eine anschließende oder spätere Wiederwahl der Richter ist ausgeschlossen.
> 3. Altersgrenze ist das Ende des Monats, in dem der Richter das 68. Lebensjahr vollendet.
> 4. **Nach Ablauf der Amtszeit führen die Richter ihre Amtsgeschäfte bis zur Ernennung des Nachfolgers fort.**
>
> ---
>
> 4. After expiry of the term of office, the judges continue their duties until the appointment of the successor.

So if they fail to appoint a successor the current judge will stay in place until that happened. Judges are only appointed once and can never be reappointed/reelected.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, the central question remains: What if the parliament does not pick any of these candidates, because there is no 2/3 majority for any of them?

Comment: @akraf The outgoing judge continues to work or the post is left unfilled (if the outgoing judge dies or is unable to work).